# How do I load MovieClip containing FLV without stuttering

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

So I have `var MC_1` which is Movieclip that contains `FLV` on its timeline. `MC_1` is supposed to appear on screen when user presses `SPACE`. It is working, except that before `MC_1` is done loading on screen, its almost played itself once, showing you last seconds and then starting its second loop.

How do I make it so that it plays itself only when it has done loading? Here's simplified code:

```
package comm {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.system.*;
    import comm.*;
    import comm.assets.*;

    public class main {

        public var MC_1:comm.assets.intro_video = new comm.assets.intro_video();
        public var cutscene_container:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function main() {
            addChild(cutscene_container);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, introstart_handler);

            function introstart_handler(event:KeyboardEvent){
                if(event.keyCode == 32){

                    cutscene_container.addChild(MC_1);
                    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, introstart_handler);

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I hope I explained my question clearly enough :P Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with solution to my problem. Thought it nice to share if anyone else is having same problem:

```
package comm {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.system.*;
    import comm.*;
    import comm.assets.*;

    public class main {

        public var MC_1:comm.assets.intro_video = new comm.assets.intro_video();
        public var cutscene_container:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function main() {
            addChild(cutscene_container);

            cutscene_container.addChild(MC_1);
            MC_1.visible = false;
            MC_1.gotoAndStop(1);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, introstart_handler);


            function introstart_handler(event:KeyboardEvent){
                if(event.keyCode == 32){
                    MC_1.visible = true;
                    MC_1.gotoAndPlay(1);

                    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, introstart_handler);
                }
            }




        }


    }
}
```

MC_1 is added to stage/container, stopped and invisible before it is needed. When it is needed (SPACE button press here) it is made visible and it will be played from frame 1.

Hope this helps if anyone else is having trouble with stuttering animation in form of FLV inside a MovieClip.

It surely did solve my problem.